# Using nested inventory lists in Ansible playbooks

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

As I am automating some of our network environment with the help of Ansible I would like to start making use of nested inventory/variable files. This foremost to keep everything tidy and well-arranged. But as of right now I can't get it to work properly and I can't tell what's the problem.

Inventory looks as followed: (dummy content)

```
interfaces:
- name: "..."
  port: "..."
  description: "..."
    parameters:
      - speed: "..."
        duplex: "..."
- name: "..."
  port: "..."
  description: "..."
    parameters:
      - speed: "..."
        duplex: "..."
```

As you see I have a "interface" list containing a "parameters" list which both I want to address in my playbooks.

Playbook looks as followed:

```
- name: Configuring network ports
  "Some network module":
    name: '{{ item.0.name }}'
    port: '{{ item.0.port }}'
    description: '{{ item.0.description }}'
    speed: '{{ item.1.speed }}'
    duplex: '{{ item.1.duplex }}'
    state: present
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ interfaces }}"
    - "{{ parameters }}
```

along the way I tried different inventory and playbook syntax's and fiddled around a bit trying to make things work but with no result.

Following are some the error messages I receive upon running the playbooks.

```
fatal: [**.**.**.**]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'parameters' is undefined"}
```

```
ERROR! could not find 'parameter' key in iterated item '{u'speed': u'...', u'duplex': u'...'}'
```

```
fatal: [**.**.**.**]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'parameter'"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's hard to reproduce errors and help you to fix them if you don't give a correct example first. And my 2 cents for yml: always validate your files with [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/) to fix errors prior to posting them in a question (you can install a local command line copy of the tool with `pip install yamllint`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is not valid YAML syntax:

```
interfaces:
- name: "..."
  port: "..."
  description: "..."
    parameters:
      - speed: "..."
        duplex: "..."
```

`description` cannot be both a scalar *and* a mapping.

You can either have

```
interfaces:
- name: "..."
  port: "..."
  description: "..."
```

or

```
interfaces:
- name: "..."
  port: "..."
  description:
    parameters:
      - speed: "..."
        duplex: "..."
```

But not both.